Selenium: не нажимается кнопка, пока не кликнешь правой кнопкой мыши
Столкнулся с проблемой: Код работает 1 раз и 10 раз не работает.
код:
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://you.com/search?q=who+are+you&tbm=youchat&cfr=chat&cid=c2_28f504cc-397c-4533-9598-3e741ad433ab')

print("Обрабатываю информацию...")

time.sleep(0.5)

# Ввод в поле
input1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#search-input-textarea').send_keys('Сколько будет 2 + 2')

time.sleep(10)

try:
    # Нажатие на кнопку ввода (1 способ)
    btn_send = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#AppProvider_Wrapper > div > div > div > div.sc-a21bf55a-0.caEJns > div > div.sc-a21bf55a-2.hFusLa > div > div.sc-d1c9dc56-0.heTnsA > div > div.sc-8c22d6b0-1.fsOFj > div > div > div > div > div > button')
    btn_send.click()
except Exception as e:
    print('callback_0.5: ', e)

    # Нажатие на кнопку ввода (В случае, если перекинуло на старую версию сайта)
    btn_send = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="AppProvider_Wrapper"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/button')
    btn_send.click()

time.sleep(15)

# Информация, которую получили на сайте
label = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#chat-history > div:nth-child(4) > div > div.sc-f70c43b-0.gRVWGt > div > div > div > p')
result= label.text
print(result)

Ссылка на сайт
Сначало я думал, что проблема в пути кнопки, которую я нажимаю. Я пробовал и XPath и CSS Selector, но это не сработало.
После я заметил, что когда я копировал путь в коде страницы, код работал. Этот момент поставил меня в тупик. Надеюсь вы поможете.
